# Joining subquery from same table on 1=1 in Oracle

Tags: oracle, join

I have a table with zip codes, latitude and longitude. I have a working query that takes a radius and latitude and longitude and returns all the zip codes within the required radius:

```
        SELECT zip.zip,
                ROUND(SDO_GEOM.SDO_DISTANCE((MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY(2001, 4326, MDSYS.SDO_POINT_TYPE(:clng, :clat, NULL), NULL, NULL)), (
                            SELECT geom
                            FROM standard_zip
                            WHERE zip = zip.zip
                            ), 0.005) / 1609.34, 2) AS dist
            FROM standard_zip zip
            WHERE zip.zip IN (
                    SELECT DISTINCT (zip) AS zip
                    FROM standard_zip c
                    WHERE SDO_FILTER(c.geom, SDO_UTIL.CIRCLE_POLYGON(:clng, :clat, :r, 5)) = 'TRUE'
                        AND SDO_RELATE(c.geom, SDO_UTIL.CIRCLE_POLYGON(:clng, :clat, :r, 5), 'mask=ANYINTERACT querytype = WINDOW') = 'TRUE'
                    )
            ORDER BY DIST
```

Since the lat and long are already in the table I would like to provide a zip code as input for the query instead of having to do a separate lookup first, but this just seems to churn forever..

```
SELECT 
    zip.zip,
    ROUND(SDO_GEOM.SDO_DISTANCE((MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY(2001, 4326, MDSYS.SDO_POINT_TYPE(inp.lng, inp.lat, NULL), NULL, NULL)), (SELECT geom FROM standard_zip WHERE zip = zip.zip), 0.005) / 1609.34, 2) AS dist,
    inp.lat,
    inp.lng
FROM standard_zip zip
LEFT JOIN (SELECT x as lng, y as lat from standard_zip where zip = :zip) inp on 1=1
WHERE zip.zip IN (
        SELECT DISTINCT (zip) AS zip
        FROM standard_zip c
        WHERE SDO_FILTER(c.geom, SDO_UTIL.CIRCLE_POLYGON(inp.lng, inp.lat, (:r * 1609.34), 5)) = 'TRUE'
            AND SDO_RELATE(c.geom, SDO_UTIL.CIRCLE_POLYGON(inp.lng, inp.lat, (:r * 1609.34), 5), 'mask=ANYINTERACT querytype = WINDOW') = 'TRUE'
        )
ORDER BY DIST
```

What am I doing wrong?

---

[MguerraTorres](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/190634/123782) suggested using a CTE, which sounds great. Here's what I tried:

```
WITH inp as (SELECT x as lng, y as lat from standard_zip where zip = :zip)
SELECT 
    zip.zip,
    ROUND(SDO_GEOM.SDO_DISTANCE((MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY(2001, 4326, MDSYS.SDO_POINT_TYPE(inp.lng, inp.lat, NULL), NULL, NULL)), (SELECT geom FROM standard_zip WHERE zip = zip.zip), 0.005) / 1609.34, 2) AS dist,
    inp.lat,
    inp.lng
FROM standard_zip zip
WHERE zip.zip IN (
        SELECT DISTINCT (zip) AS zip
        FROM standard_zip c
        WHERE SDO_FILTER(c.geom, SDO_UTIL.CIRCLE_POLYGON(inp.lng, inp.lat, (:r * 1609.34), 5)) = 'TRUE'
            AND SDO_RELATE(c.geom, SDO_UTIL.CIRCLE_POLYGON(inp.lng, inp.lat, (:r * 1609.34), 5), 'mask=ANYINTERACT querytype = WINDOW') = 'TRUE'
        )
ORDER BY DIST
```

Problem is, Oracle says `inp.lng` is an invalid identifier. Why?

Comment: Try `CROSS JOIN`

Comment: It is useless to have `WHERE zip.zip IN (SELECT DISTINCT (zip) AS zip`. Just write `WHERE zip.zip IN (SELECT zip FROM ...`. `DISTINCT` may slow down your query.

Comment: inp.lng is an invalid identifier because you have no tables called inp anywhere in the definition (that I can see).  Edit: ahh I see it's what you named your CTE table.  Gotcha.

Comment: Try commenting out the 3rd and 4th columns (lat/lng) in the select for a second.  If the query works, then the CTE is getting flushed due to your "dist" column.  I don't think that's the case though.

Comment: @MguerraTorres - Even if I comment off all the selected columns except  zip, and remove the order by, it still says `inp.lat` is an invalid identifier in the where clause

Comment: haha gotcha.  Yeah CTE tables should be treated as normal ones.  You still need to join to inp as if it was a real table.  your WITH statement only defines INP, it doesn't include it into the SELECT query on its own.  As far as your SELECT knows, inp doesn't even exist.

Comment: oh, duh... ok, thank you. i fixed the error but the join is still really slowing things down. i appreciate your help anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're cross joining to your "inp" query, but then using the results from that in the where clause for the subquery of your main where clause. Effectively then the subquery will run once for every row of the zip table. Which will slow things a tad.

I'm slightly rusty as to what you could achieve with any PL/SQL around this, so in pure SQL you could write it as:

```
SELECT 
  zip.zip,
  ROUND(SDO_GEOM.SDO_DISTANCE((MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY(2001, 4326, MDSYS.SDO_POINT_TYPE(inp.lng, inp.lat, NULL), NULL, NULL)), (SELECT geom FROM standard_zip WHERE zip = zip.zip), 0.005) / 1609.34, 2) AS dist,
  inp.lat,
  inp.lng
FROM standard_zip zip
WHERE zip.zip IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT (zip) AS zip
    FROM standard_zip c
    WHERE SDO_FILTER(c.geom, SDO_UTIL.CIRCLE_POLYGON((SELECT x as lng from standard_zip where zip = :zip),
                                                     (SELECT y as lat from standard_zip where zip = :zip),
                                                     (:r * 1609.34), 5)) = 'TRUE'
        AND SDO_RELATE(c.geom, SDO_UTIL.CIRCLE_POLYGON((SELECT x as lng from standard_zip where zip = :zip),
                                                       (SELECT y as lat from standard_zip where zip = :zip),
                                                       (:r * 1609.34), 5), 'mask=ANYINTERACT querytype = WINDOW') = 'TRUE'
    )
ORDER BY DIST
```

Might be a little quicker. Essentially it ought to behave much like your original working query did.

Comment: wow.. this worked. i thought about doing this but never tried it because it's frankly, sorta dirty looking, but it works... i still haven't tried [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/190634/123782) but so far this is the only way i've been able to successfully do this. **note** i had to remove `inp.lat`, `inp.lng` from the column list and replace the same with the subquery on line 3. thanks for your help!

Comment: Good stuff :) I could see this is sort of what you were angling for. I have a worry though - are there zip codes for which there are more than one entry in the standard_zip table? i.e. is zip a primary key? If so, the query may break for one of those zip codes, but if not, then it looks like it's superfluous to fetch a list of zips then requery the same table again using that list as a filter

Comment: hmm.. no evidently the only index on this table is the spatial index on the geometry column. i suppose that's why the original author had the distinct on the the zip column :/ , strange. if i end up going this route i guess i could just get the record where `rownum=1` or something. also, i didn't mean dirty, i apologize, i just meant redundant. this is still the only thing that's working for me. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be this:

```
SELECT 
    zip.zip,
    ROUND(SDO_GEOM.SDO_DISTANCE((MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY(2001, 4326, MDSYS.SDO_POINT_TYPE(inp.lng, inp.lat, NULL), NULL, NULL)), (SELECT geom FROM standard_zip WHERE zip = zip.zip), 0.005) / 1609.34, 2) AS dist,
    inp.lat,
    inp.lng
FROM standard_zip zip
   CROSS JOIN (SELECT x as lng, y as lat from standard_zip where zip = :zip) inp
WHERE zip.zip IN (
        SELECT zip
        FROM standard_zip c
        WHERE SDO_FILTER(c.geom, SDO_UTIL.CIRCLE_POLYGON(inp.lng, inp.lat, (:r * 1609.34), 5)) = 'TRUE'
            AND SDO_RELATE(c.geom, SDO_UTIL.CIRCLE_POLYGON(inp.lng, inp.lat, (:r * 1609.34), 5), 'mask=ANYINTERACT querytype = WINDOW') = 'TRUE'
        )
ORDER BY DIST;
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, however this churned forever too. i think i'll need to come at this from an entirely different angle. thanks for answering.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using CTE:

```
WITH CTE_ZIP 
AS
(SELECT DISTINCT (zip) AS zip
                FROM standard_zip c
                WHERE SDO_FILTER(c.geom, SDO_UTIL.CIRCLE_POLYGON(:clng, :clat, :r, 5)) = 'TRUE'
                    AND SDO_RELATE(c.geom, SDO_UTIL.CIRCLE_POLYGON(:clng, :clat, :r, 5), 'mask=ANYINTERACT querytype = WINDOW') = 'TRUE')
```

Then use the CTE_ZIP table as you would a standard table to join.  Or even use WHERE EXISTS/WHERE NOT EXISTS.

```
  SELECT zip.zip,
            ROUND(SDO_GEOM.SDO_DISTANCE((MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY(2001, 4326, MDSYS.SDO_POINT_TYPE(:clng, :clat, NULL), NULL, NULL)), (
                        SELECT geom
                        FROM standard_zip
                        WHERE zip = zip.zip
                        ), 0.005) / 1609.34, 2) AS dist
        FROM standard_zip zip
        INNER JOIN CTE_ZIP 
            ON zip.zip = CTE_ZIP.zip
        ORDER BY DIST
```

Comment: I had no idea about CTEs. I've seen them but never written one. This is ideal, but you have the idea backwards. I tried to implement it but got an error. I will update the question, please have a look.

Comment: Not so sure I have the idea backwards.  I just implemented it successfully in a similar situation about an hour ago.  But hey, as long as it helps you get where you need to go I'm happy.

Comment: so far it hasn't help me. i'm hoping it will. problem is, your implementation as shown still requires me to input the latitude and longitude into the query which is the entire point of the question. i already have a working query that gets the results with the lat, lng.